# Is vector in struct time consuming? Is it better to use a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a struct in C++ like this:

```
struct MyStruct 
{
    someType v1;
    someType2 v2;    
    someType3 v3;
    someType4 f1();

    std::vector<someType> myVector;
} ;
```

It will be very often used in forms like this:

```
 //some process... after which a std::vector<someType> vec1 is generated 
 MyStruct myStruct;    
 myStruct.myVector = vec1;
```

Since vec1 is relative large. I want to know if it costs much time by doing the assignment `myStruct.myVector = vec1;`

Should I use a pointer to myVector in MyStruct to make it faster? And how?

Comment: `std::move(vec1)` Problem solved. Avoid naked pointers, there's always a better way.

Comment: It really depends on your use-case.

Comment: As others have said, move construction may be what you want. But if you need `vec1` to continue to hold its original value after the assignment then move construction won't work. If you are sure that `myStruct.myVector` will never be used after `vec1` is destroyed then a naked pointer is exactly right. Otherwise, consider using a shared pointer.

Comment: By the way, if move construction isn't right for you, consider just leaving the code as it is and not worrying about the copy! It sounds like a cop-out but often in situations like this the thing that looks like it's going to hold up your program doesn't turn out to be the slow bit. A common mistake is optimizing before you really know what's going to be a problem; this is called "premature optimization".

Comment: Don’t get distracted by the surrounding `struct`. The question is whether using `std::vector` is better (in some unspecified context) than using a pointer, and the answer is, almost always yes.

Answer (score 11):

> Since vec1 is relative large. I want to know if it costs much time by doing the assignment

It costs time in linear proportion to the size of the vector.

> Should I use a pointer to vec in MyStruct to make it faster?

Given the problem that you've described, no I would not suggest you use a pointer unless you've left out relevant details.

You could move assign the vector (since C++11), or swap it (prior to C++11). But that assumes that you don't need `vec1` for anything else.

Comment: "Should I use a pointer to vec in MyStruct to make it faster? No." -1 Many uses of naked pointers in C have been replaced with better constructions in C++, but sometimes a naked pointer is just fine. An unqualified "no" is simply wrong. "Maybe" or "probably not" is the real answer.

Comment: @ArthurTacca If you need a naked pointer, you don't need stackoverflow, and vice versa.

Comment: @ArthurTacca `but sometimes a naked pointer is just fine` Correct, but nothing in OP's question suggests that **they** need a pointer.

Comment: @user2079303 That's true, but nothing in OP's question suggests that any other solution (move, shared pointer) would necessarily work for them either. Without more details, the overall answer to their question is "it depends".

Comment: @ArthurTacca fair enough. But since just "it depends" is not very useful by itself and pretty much implied in every SO answer, and iterating all possibilities is not practical - there are infinitely many qualifications that OP may have forgotten to mention -> I went for the most likely solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fundamental difference between `std::vector<someType> myVector` and `std::vector<someType*> myVector`. The non-pointer version actually owns and stores the data. This means once the assignment is made changes to the original variable will not result in changes to your vector (deep copy).

In the pointer version, storage is external to the vector. This means that changes to the original will result in changes to your vector (shallow copy). The is another knock on effect as well.

Since storage is external to your vector, it is your responsibility to ensure that the original sticks around for longer than your vector. Otherwise bad things will happen. This can be mitigated with a `std::shared_ptr` but you are still aliasing the same memory.

So the question you need to ask is whether you require a shallow copy or a deep copy.

Also `std::move` will only save you a copy if data is stored external to the `struct` (like an stl-container) otherwise you will need to move a `std::unique_ptr<someType>` to save the copy.

Comment: I think they actually meant a pointer to the whole vector i.e. `std::vector<someType>*`. This is interesting too though.

Comment: Your `std::vector<*someType>` is invalid syntax, I think you mean `std::vector<someType*>`.

Comment: Edited the post